# Printing square using specified character and multiplying chars

Tags: c

> Write a programme that prints a square pattern of side length M of any single character specified by the user using a single for loop and a single if else statement. You should define both M and the character constant C as preprocessor statements.

I actually did that but I wonder is there any easier way to solve this problem. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main()
{

    int M, i = 1;
    char C, G[1000];

    printf("Input a value for side length:\n");
    scanf("%d", &M);

    printf("Input a character for pattern:\n");
    scanf(" %c", &C);

    for (; i <= M; i++) {
        printf("%c", C);

        if (i <= M) {
            memset(G, C, (M - 1));
            G[M - 1] = '\0';
            puts(G);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: define "easier"

Comment: "You should define both M and the character constant C as preprocessor statements." Does that refer to macros or what?

Comment: If "**any** single character" pathologically includes `'\0'`, that eliminates printing _strings_ and if it includes spaces, `scanf(" %c", &C);`, will fail to read the character.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the `memset` *outside* of the loop *once*.

You can just do `puts` inside the loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main()
{

    int M, i = 1;
    char C, G[1000];

    printf("Input a value for side length:\n");
    scanf("%d", &M);

    printf("Input a character for pattern:\n");
    scanf(" %c", &C);

    memset(G, C, M);
    G[M] = '\0';

    for (; i <= M; i++)
        puts(G);

    return 0;
}
```

For an input of `8` rows and a char of `*`, the output is:

```
Input a value for side length:
8
Input a character for pattern:
*
********
********
********
********
********
********
********
********
```

---

**UPDATE:**

After rereading the requirements, if `C` and `M` *must* be macros, the code should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef M
#error M not defined
#endif

#ifndef C
#error C not defined
#endif

int
main()
{

    int i = 1;
    char G[1000];

    memset(G, C, M);
    G[M] = '\0';

    for (; i <= M; i++)
        puts(G);

    return 0;
}
```

And, the program should be compiled with:

```
cc -o program -DM=8 -DC="'*'" program.c
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
int M1 = M + 1;
for (int i = 0; i < M*M1; ++i) {
  if (i % M1 == M) putchar('\n');
  else putchar(C);
}
```

Comment: Nice outside the box thinking.

Comment: Or `for (int i = 1; i <= M*M1; ++i) putchar(i%M1 ? C : '\n');`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The assignment asked for one `if` statement

Comment: OK `for (int i = 1; i <= M*M1; ++i) if (1) putchar(i%M1 ? C : '\n');`